# Javascript: Recursion, jQuery Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

Working on a navigation menu script with jQuery. The script is being designed with recursion so that there is no hard coded limit to the number of levels the menu has.

I'll start with the code:

```
navigationMenu.prototype.reset = function ( ulElement, colorIndex, colors ) { //Color index should always be 1 when directly calling this function
var listItems = $(ulElement.children);
var numItems = listItems.length;
var targetWidth = (100 / numItems) + '%';

listItems.each( function ( x ) {
    var children = $(listItems[x].children);
    var xT = $(listItems[x]).prop('tagName');
    var subMenu = null;

    children.each( function ( y ) {
        var yT = $(children[y]).prop('tagName'); 

        if (yT == 'UL') {
            subMenu = $(children[y]);
        } else if (yT == 'A') {
            $(children[y]).css('background-color', colors[colorIndex-1]); //Offset by 1 to facilitate for 0 indexed arrays
            $(children[y]).hover( function () { //Set hover color to the opposite
               $(children[y]).css('background-color',colors[(3-colorIndex)-1]); //3-1 = 2 and 3-2 = 1, subtract 1 to facilitate 0 indexed arrays
            }, function() {
                $(children[y]).css('background-color',colors[colorIndex-1]); //3-1 = 2 and 3-2 = 1, subtract 1 to facilitate 0 indexed arrays
            }); //Rest of style SHOULD be handled by css (width 100%, text color, text align)
        }
    });

    if (subMenu !== null) { //Recurse
        navigationMenu.prototype.reset(subMenu, (3 - colorIndex), colors); //Not defined?
    }

    if (xT == 'LI') { //Format the element
        $(listItems[x]).css('width',targetWidth);
        $(listItems[x]).css('background-color', colors[colorIndex]);
    }
});
};
```

Next, The error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null <-whitespace-> jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
```

What concerns me is that the error does not seem to come directly from my code, rather, a function within the jQuery library; however, I'm placing good money on the fact that it is because of something I did wrong.

A live demo can be found here:
http://proofoftheilluminati.com/test/test.html

For an idea of the final look of the menu you can see the top level with hover effect and a simple JS script that maths the link widths here:
http://proofoftheilluminati.com/test/index.html

Script: 
http://proofoftheilluminati.com/test/scripts/menu.js

I'm hosting a freshly downloaded copy of jQuery version 1.11.1:
http://proofoftheilluminati.com/test/scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js

What it should be doing:
Top level list should be orange with black over effect
second level list should be black with orange hover effect
third level list should be same as first, etc.

Positioning is handled by external css file

What it is doing:
Handles top level list correctly, seems to error before style second level list.

Please let me know if I left anything out. I try to be thorough.

Edit: The supplied code has a comment on the line that calls itself:

```
//Not defined?
```

This was left over from a previous error, I was having trouble getting it to recognize the recursive function call. I tried the following lines here and they would not allow the function to progress:

```
this.reset(subMenu, (3 - colorIndex), colors);
reset(subMenu, (3 - colorIndex), colors);
navigationMenu.reset(subMenu, (3 - colorIndex), colors);
```

Additionally, this function is called when the document is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    s = new navigationMenu('#NavMenu', '#884106', '#000000', -1);
});
```

Edit: modified code to use x/y instead of index and xT/yT instead of tag (removed nested variables with same name)

Comment: Avoid in all case to use same names for nested variables

Comment: I felt odd using index twice. I also feel odd using different names for the same idea.

Comment: But you should use `this` instead of `listItems[index]` and `children[index]`

Comment: I don't intent to say your wrong or argue @A.Wolff but I feel that's a style choice. Tests show no difference in processing time/efficiency and using this doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: One thing that is definitely a problem is the line `navigationMenu.prototype.reset.call(me, subMenu, (3 - colorIndex), colors);` in menu.js. That is calling the `reset` function with `navigationMenu.prototype` as `this`. You need to do var me=this as the first statement in `reset()` and change that line to `me.reset(subMenu(3-colorIndex), colors)`. It doesn't fix the problem, but it's definitely wrong.

Comment: @A.Wolff Since we've already started making suggestions about style. Toby, constructor functions should be PascalCase, `new NavigationMenu()`, not `new navigationMenu()` That will make it much easier for other JavaScript devs to look at it.

Comment: @JuanMendes I honestly prefer all lower case. I only put caps in there because other people seem to like it. As for the "It doesn't fix the problem, but it's definitely wrong" thing... I can't take that comment seriously. I'm not a professional by any means, I do this as a hobby.  You're probably correct in saying that my style does not match industry standards... don't care.

Comment: @Toby You can't take that comments seriously? Or you just don't understand what I meant? That doesn't break your code because you're never referring to `this` in that function. I guess we're just wasting our time trying to explain best practices to someone who.... doesn't care. If you're asking others to read your code, you should care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first call `navigationMenu.prototype.reset`, I'm guessing `ulElement` is a DOM element, but when you call it recursively, you are passing it `subMenu`, which is a jQuery object. That will be a problem for the following line:

```
var listItems = $(ulElement.children);
```

Try changing the following line of code:

```
navigationMenu.prototype.reset(subMenu, (3 - colorIndex), colors);
```

To:

```
navigationMenu.prototype.reset(subMenu[0], (3 - colorIndex), colors);
```

---

I prefer to always prefix variables that refer to jQuery objects with "$" to keep them straight.

You could also use `this` inside the functions given to `.each()`. So instead of:

```
children.each(function(index) {
    var tag = $(children[index]).prop('tagName');
```

You could have:

```
children.each(function() {
    var $child = $(this),
        tag = $child.prop('tagName');
```

You could also consider using the jQuery `.children()` method, instead of the `children` DOM element property

Comment: interesting feedback, you are entirely correct in the difference, changing the first occurrence to a jQuery select causes the issue immediately rather then waiting for the second occurrence. As for the comment about "this," I don't prefer that method and my tests show there is no performance difference between the two.

Comment: That's why I ask you guys. Your fix worked perfectly. Thanks!